# How to Setup the Block Height to 100% Just Using CSS Float

Tags: css, css-float

I know it's possible to setup the block width 100% and it will extend the screen horizontally, as in the snippet code below. But, why doesn't it work for the height?

```
.block1{
     width:100%;
     float:left;
     background-color:yellow;
}
```

The above block goes into the container, which was used `overflow:hidden;` but it didn't help. Is there a way to setup the block height to 100%?

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec of `height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **<percentage>**
>  Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   containing block. If the height of the containing block is not
>   specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this
>   element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

If not, the height of an element with `height: 100%` would depend on its parent's height, and if its parent's height depends on content's height (`height: auto`), it would be a circular definition.

Comment: +1 I.e. the *parent* should have an explicit `height` to get percentage value to work for the `height` of the *child* (Same for `min-height` property of children elements)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not 100% of the screen width, it's 100% of the parent element's width (which, in your case, is probably the same width as the screen).

You cannot do height: 100% because the browser doesn't know how high the parent element is. It's impossible to calculate, so it ends up being ignored by the browser.

You need to use javascript to find out how tall the screen is.